# How to connect plaid to stripe using django python

Tags: python, django, plaid

I was using stripe in django but i am new for plaid . Now i want to connect plaid with my django app and than pay with plaid + stripe.

I refer below document but i cant understand how to work 
document link:
https://plaid.com/docs/stripe/
https://stripe.com/docs/ach#using-plaid

I was test below code but than next what to do i don't know

```
<button id='linkButton'>Open Plaid Link</button>
<script src="https://cdn.plaid.com/link/v2/stable/link-initialize.js"></script>
<script>
var linkHandler = Plaid.create({
  env: 'sandbox',
  clientName: 'Stripe/Plaid Test',
  key: '1bde1c39022bbcecaccde8cc92182d',
  product: ['auth'],
  selectAccount: true,
  onSuccess: function(public_token, metadata) {
    // Send the public_token and account ID to your app server.
    console.log('public_token: ' + public_token);
    console.log('account ID: ' + metadata.account_id);





  },
  onExit: function(err, metadata) {
    // The user exited the Link flow.
    if (err != null) {
      // The user encountered a Plaid API error prior to exiting.
    }
  },
});

// Trigger the Link UI
document.getElementById('linkButton').onclick = function() {
  linkHandler.open();
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the correct place to post this since I can't find a direct message, but I am also interested in an answer to this question.

BInjal, where are you running the python? My impression is that you need to host and run this on a separate server from the stripe server. Is this correct?